# How do I get Ubuntu to open?

Tags: boot, system-installation

I got Yakkety installed, finally, and it booted, but I don't have a clue how to get it to a usable state. The screen is blank. When it was installing I ticked the choice to require a password but there's no prompt to enter it. The answer is probably obvious but not to me.